# Export mail from Windows Live Mail 2012 to Exchange format

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, windows-live-mail

I recently installed Office 365 on my mom's computer, and she wanted to transfer all her email from her old email client (Windows Live Mail 2012). I foolishly assumed she set it up using IMAP so I'd be done in a minute. But alas, it was set up using POP3. And to make matters worse, she had both folders hierarchically located under her email account, and others in completely separate "Storage Folders".

I figured I'd give the export function in WLM 2012 a try. Everything seemed to work until it got to about message 40 (out of a few hundred). I don't get an error and the program just crashes.

I tried moving the files but I think the files Outlook uses have another format than those used in WLM 2012.

If anyone knows how to transfer old messages from a POP3 setup in Windows Live Mail 2012 to an IMAP setup in Outlook 2016, I would be helped out a bunch!

Here's some images to explain what I mean:

- [This is where I found the Export tool](https://ducohosting.com/screenshots/D_v3NWt2Zu_v3NWt2Zu.png)
- [Export to Exchange format](https://ducohosting.com/screenshots/D_zqy10HCH_zqy10HCH.png)
- [I want to export all folders](https://ducohosting.com/screenshots/D_2q4MhUH8_2q4MhUH8.png)
- [Windows Live Mail 2012 wants to export *no* folders](https://ducohosting.com/screenshots/D_anslmwFn_anslmwFn.png) - I get this almost immediately after clicking export.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use another tool. For example, the free [Import Messages from EML Files](https://www.outlookfreeware.com/en/products/all/OutlookMessagesImportEML/) can easily import all your WLM mails into Outlook. Please note, that WLM is using EML files to store emails, so you can import them right into Outlook.

DISCLAIMER: I recommend this tool because I'm one of the developers, so feel free to ask any further questions.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to copy the messages into Outlook using the tool. It's kind of a shame I had to do it folder-by-folder though, would've loved to see a recursive option.

Comment: Subfolders is an option of commercial edition.